# calling useQuery conditionally returns wrong output only for the first time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Please help me understand why am I getting no items on first request.
I have this component ExportData that calls Context only when prompted, dialogConfirmation is linked to a button, snippet:

**ExportData:**

```
import useItem from '../../context/ItemsContext'

const ExportData = () => {
  const { items, getAll } = useItem()

  const dialogConfirmation = confirm => {
    if (confirm) {
      getAll()
    }
  }
}
```

**ItemsContext:**

```
import React, {
  useState,
  useReducer,
  createContext,
  useContext,
  useEffect,
} from 'react'
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/client'
import { CURRENT_MONTH, ALL_ITEMS } from '../graphql/queries'
import itemReducer from '../reducers/itemReducer'

export const ItemProvider = ({ children }) => {
  let items = []
  const [all, setAll] = useState(false)

  const selectedMonth = dayjs(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM')
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(itemReducer, [])

  const result = useQuery(all ? ALL_ITEMS : CURRENT_MONTH, {
    variables: all ?  null : { selectedMonth },
  })

  if (result.data && result.data.getCurrentMonth) {
    items = [...result.data.getCurrentMonth]
  }

  if (result.data && result.data.getItems) {
    items = [...result.data.getItems]
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (result.data && result.data.getCurrentMonth) {
      dispatch({
        type: 'ALL',
        items: result.data.getCurrentMonth,
      })
    }
    if (result.data && result.data.getItems) {
      dispatch({
        type: 'ALL',
        items: result.data.getItems,
      })
    }
  }, [result.data])

  const getAll = () => {
    setAll(true)
  }

  const value = {
    items: state.items,
    getAll,
  }
  return <ItemContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</ItemContext.Provider>
}
```

**Reducer:**

```
const itemReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ALL':
      return {
        ...state,
        items: action.items,
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Query **CURRENT_MONTH** returns only items from current month - that should be the default one.

Query **ALL_ITEMS** returns all items in database.

What happens currently, when I use the `getAll` function in `ExportData`, on the first try, it returns only the items from current month, however on the second try, it returns correct output(all data).

When debugging itemReducer, all items are in the `action.items` however the output within the component gets only the old data...On the second try however, it works fine.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why do you need reducer in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here:

1. Component is initially rendered (no data yet)
2. `useEffect`s are fired: (inside component) does nothing, (inside `useQuery`) fires request to gql api
3. after some time when request is fulfilled state inside `useQuery` is set with data
4. Becouse of that component gets rerender (data is present but not yet used in `state.items` becouse dispatch was not fired yet)
5. `useEffect`s are fired and this time dispatch is called.
6. Component rerenders again because dispatch changed useReducer state and this time state has items inside

In this process react renders 3 times. If you place `console.log(state.items)` inside component it will look like this:

```
[]             // no data yet
[]             // data is present but not yet used by `state`
[<your data>]  // data is present and used by state
```

You can solve that by removing useEffect and useReducer:

1. Component is initially rendered (no data yet)
2. `useEffect`s are fired: (inside component) does nothing, (inside `useQuery`) fires request to gql api
3. after some time when request is fulfilled state inside `useQuery` is set with data
4. Becouse of that component gets rerender (data is passed directly to value)

In this process react renders 2 times. If you place `console.log(items)` inside component it will look like this:

```
[]            // no data yet
[<your data>] // data is present and used
```

```
import React, {
  useState,
  createContext,
  useContext,
} from 'react'
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/client'
import { CURRENT_MONTH, ALL_ITEMS } from '../graphql/queries'

export const ItemProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [all, setAll] = useState(false)

  const selectedMonth = dayjs(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM')

  const result = useQuery(all ? ALL_ITEMS : CURRENT_MONTH, {
    variables: all ?  null : { selectedMonth },
  })

  const getAll = () => {
    setAll(true)
  }

  const items = result?.data.getCurrentMonth || result?.data.getItems || []

  const value = {
    items,
    getAll,
  }
  return <ItemContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</ItemContext.Provider>
}
```